# Magento2: Block with arguments

Tags: magento2, blocks

I'm using Magestore's mega menu extension and using a plain content for rendering menu dropdowns. There, I want to use dynamic block's. I tried adding my dynamic block in xml layout file and its working fine there. The code is as below:

```
<block class="Sebwite\Sidebar\Block\Categorymenutree" name="category-menu-tree" as="catmenutree" before="-" template="Sebwite_Sidebar::categorymenutree.phtml" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="menu_id" xsi:type="number">239</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

So my question is how can I add this block from backend with arguments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Content > Pages and click on a page where you want to show your static block. Then add this short-code

```
{{block class="Sebwite\\Sidebar\\Block\\Categorymenutree" menu_id="239"}}
```

`menu_id` attribute is your argument name.

Comment: Sorry but its not working.

Comment: It seems that mega menu extension doesn't work properly. When I use "content" as content type and then add my block and widgets in it. The code is directly shown at frontend rather dynamic HTML. http://prntscr.com/cnrx90